# Synchronous processing of mongo query in node JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, apache-kafka

I am trying to read each message from Kafka topic in node JS and search for any duplicate record exists of the message received in mongo DB, else to insert the new record in mongo DB. Below is the code written for the same.

As NodeJS does asynchronous message processing, next message from Kafka topic is read and processed before the first message is queried from mongo DB and inserted if its not a duplicate.

```
var dataHandler = function (messageSet, topic, partition) {
    messageSet.forEach(function (m) {        
        var m_val=m.message.value.toString('utf8');
        if((m_val.slice(100 ,108)=="XXXXXXXX") || (m_val.slice(100 ,108)=="YYYYYYYY")){ 
            senderInfo.requestID=m_val.slice(100,108);
            senderInfo.fileIdentifier=m_val.slice(140,190);
            senderInfo.sequenceNo=m_val.slice(191,199);
            senderInfo.recCount=m_val.slice(200,210);
            senderInfo.totHash=m_val.slice(213,231);

            //* store the data in Mongo. check for duplicate record
            //*var insert1 = JSON.parse(m.message.value.toString('utf8'));


            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
                assert.equal(null, err);
                console.log("Connected correctly to MongoDB server.");
                /*mongodb = db; */
                var db = client.db('Unitech');           

                var getResult = (callback) => {                  
                    console.log("request ID before mongo DB query is:"+senderInfo.requestID);    
                    db.collection("Instream").find({"requestID":senderInfo.requestID})
                        .toArray(function(err, result) {            
                            if (err) throw err;                                
                            callback(result.length);
                        });
                }           
                getResult((result) => { 
                    if(result>0){
                        console.log("Duplicate message sent:"+senderInfo.requestID+" "+senderInfo.sequenceNo);
                    } else{               
                        db.collection('Instream').insertOne(senderInfo);
                        console.log("One message inserted");
                        client.close();
                    }
                });            
            });

        }
    }); 
};
```

Is there a way I can handle the mongo query in synchronous way?

### Code reference: